# How to count all the elements in a column with reference to another column Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following data frame.

> Port | Label | OtherColumnsFilledWithData
> 80  | 1 |
> 60  | 0 |
> 40  | 1 |
> 10  | 0 |
> 80  | 0 |
> 60  | 0 |
> 80  | 1 |

I want to create another dataframe that says how many of each ports there are with how many times the label is either 1 or 0.

> Port | # | Label=1 | Label=2
> 80   | 3 | 2 | 1
> 60   | 2 | 0 | 2
> 40   | 1 | 1 | 1

Comment: What object is the data stored in? A 2d list, a dictionary...?

Comment: Pandas dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It´s possible to make this with a pivot, but in this case i aggregate one more column to the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Port': [80, 40,60,10,80,60,80],
                   'Label': [1, 0,1,0,0,0,1],
                   'Qty':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]})
```

Next, with a pivot_table you can create the table:

```
    df_final = pd.pivot_table(df, columns=['Label'], index=['Port'], 
               values=['Qty'], aggfunc=np.sum).fillna(0)
```

[image: df_final]

Finally, to get the total freq, apply:

```
df_final['Total'] = df_final[('Qty', 0)] + df_final[('Qty', 1)]
```

[image: df_final]

Comment: Question. How do I access the column in Qty1. I want all the ports where Qty1 != 0 and Qty!=0 . Do you know how to do this?

Comment: With this df_final[('Qty', 0)], is a Multiindex dataframe, you need to specify the Qty and the index

Comment: I tried running this df_final[(df_final.select_dtypes(include=[('Qty', 1)]) != 0).any(1)] but i got this error 'data type "Qty" not understood'